# I want to lock my Macbook lid shut. Where to buy? Alternatives?

Tags: hardware, physical

I'm attempting to lock down a computer from unauthorized access. I own a macbook pro late 2011.

## Backstory

I've gone through the basics with file vault and firmware password etc. I'm also getting a couple of yubikey-like USB dongles for password management. I've read passwords can be circumvented with things such as Inception, so I'm looking for a multi-layered approach to security.

## Wanted: special lock

I'm looking for a laptop lock that wraps around the laptop lid --not around a chair or table. A Kensington laptop lock that prevents physical access to the machine from those without a combination code. (I'm not looking for a keyed version.) Do they make such a thing? Is there a better option?

Comment: You might be able to find something on the applelocks website

Comment: Will your Laptop fit inside a Safe?

Comment: Firewire attacks and similar can circumvent that. Shut it down and use full disk encryption instead